# How to read file in opposite direction in C++?

Tags: c++, file, ifstream

For example, i open ifstream, and i want it to read not from current position to end, like always, but in reverse direction (from current position to start)?

Comment: Might be an XY problem; if you want the data backwards then read it forwards and read the resulting data backwards.

Comment: I'd like to know the reason for _that_ :D

Comment: Seek to the end, then seek backwards X bytes, where X is the number of bytes you want to read. Then seek X + Y bytes backwards, where Y is the number of bytes you want to read next, etc.

Comment: Usually, operating systems do not support it. You have to determine the size of the file, seek to the end - one page, read a page, process and repeat. (Here, you can determine the page size)

Comment: `std::ifstream file("input.txt"); std::vector<char> contents { std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{file}, std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{} };` .. and then iterate `contents` using `rbegin()` and `rend()`. Well this should work great for smaller files.

Comment: @Mats Not a duplicate. This OP says nothing about line-by-line. Please be more careful with your dupe hammer.

Comment: Sorry, missed that it said line-by-line in that one too (I saw it in the title of another one similar to it). I can't believe this isn't a dupe tho'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use random file operations in C++ for this.

For `ifstream ss`, you can write the command `ss.seekg(0, ios::end)` to move your pointer in the text file to the end of the text file. Now you can move `x` number of bytes from your current location using the `ss.seekg(-x, ios::current)` current, and then read the data from that location in the forward direction. This is however a messy solution as you would need to know how many bits to move backward, or have to calculate that repeatedly. Refer to http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/137-random-file-io/ for more information on Random file operations in C++.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to read single characters, you can to something like this:

```
    is.seekg(0,is.end);
    while(is.tellg()>1)
    {
            is.seekg(-2,ios::cur);
            char ch;
            is.read(&ch,1);
            cout<<ch<<" ";
    }
```